# What is the significance of the letter "d" in Linux file (path) names?

Tags: linux, path

What is the significance of the letter "d"?  Don't think it matters, but I am using CentOS.

For instance,

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d
/etc/yum.repos.d
```

Comment: Well - **d** irectory?

Comment: @Andreas.  Now you are just making fun of me :)

Comment: more suitable for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user1032531 No, really not! From the answers, I see that some people read it as "daemon", but I usually read it as "directory" - it is normally a configuration directory which contains several configuration files which are concatenated together and parsed by some server or daemon.

Comment: Just read your question more carefully - you are actually referring to both directory (`/etc/httpd/conf.d`), and daemon (`/etc/httpd`). So I think that @Marc's answer is the most complete one.

Comment: @Andreas.  You think the d in httpd refers to directory and not daemon?

Comment: @user1032531 No, as Marc says, the `d` in "httpd" refers to "daemon", but the `d` in "conf.d" refers to "directory"

Comment: @Andreas  I just read your comment more carefully, and also realized what you said.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1032531 Note that you can use html markup to [make parts of a word bold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140706/how-do-i-make-part-of-a-word-bold-using-markdown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the `daemon`, that is, the program runnning in background in the system and performing the actions.

For example, for `httpd` we can can find this reference: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Hypertext-Transfer-Protocol-daemon-HTTPD

> On the Web, each server has an HTTPD or Hypertext Transfer Protocol
>   daemon that waits in attendance for requests to come in from the rest
>   of the Web. A daemon is a program that is "an attendant power or
>   spirit" (Webster's). It sits waiting for requests to come in and then
>   forwards them to other processes as appropriate.

These daemons are normally starting when the system boots and you can see them with basic `ps -ef`.

Answer (score 5):

`d` stands for daemon.

> In multitasking computer operating systems, a daemon (/ˈdeɪmən/ or /ˈdiːmən/)[1] is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user. Traditionally daemon names end with the letter d: for example, syslogd is the daemon that implements the system logging facility and sshd is a daemon that services incoming SSH connections.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)

Answer (score 3):

http(daemon), http(daemon).conf, conf.(dir)

Comment: I take it pluginconf.(dir) and /etc/yum.repos.(dir) as well?

Comment: `.d` is usually "directory". `d` at the end without a `.` (e.g. `httpd`) usually indicates daemon. It's not a set-in-stone rule, though. e.g. sendmail uses `/etc/sendmail`, with no trailing `d` in sight, even though it's a daemon AND that's its config directory.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that is shorthand for `daemon`, which is essentially a program that runs in the background (usually a server, but not always).  so /etc/httpd.conf would be the configuration file for the http daemon.